# toObservable doesn't seem to be working

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I'm using Web UI to do observable data binding.  Here is the brief snippet of code I'm working with:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:json';
import 'package:web_ui/web_ui.dart';
import 'package:admin_front_end/admin_front_end.dart';

//var properties = toObservable(new List<Property>()..add(new Property(1, new Address('','','','','',''))));
var properties = toObservable(new List<Property>());

void main() {
    HttpRequest.request('http://localhost:26780/api/properties', requestHeaders: {'Accept' : 'application/json'})
        .then((HttpRequest req){
          final jsonObjects = parse(req.responseText);
          for(final obj in jsonObjects){
            properties.add(new Property.fromJsonObject(obj));
          }
    });
}
```

In index.html, I bind `properties` to it's respective property in the template:

```html
<div is="x-property-table" id="property_table" properties="{{properties}}"></div>
```

In the first snippet of code, I'm populating the observable `properties` list, but it never reflects in the UI (I've stepped through the code and made sure elements were in-fact being added).  If I pre-populate the list (see the commented out line), it does display, so the binding is at least working properly.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is most likely that you don't have any variables or types marked as `@observable`. In lack of observables, Web UI relies on call to `watchers.dispatch()` in order to update GUI.

You have following options:

1) import watchers library and call `dispatch()` explicitly:

```java
import 'package:web_ui/watcher.dart' as watchers;
...
void main() {
    HttpRequest.request(...)
        .then((HttpRequest req){
          for(...) { properties.add(new Property.fromJsonObject(obj)); }
          watchers.dispatch(); // <-- update observers
    });
}
```

2) mark any field of your `x-property-table` component as observable, or just the component type, e.g.:

```java
@observable // <-- this alone should be enough
class PropertyTable extends WebComponent {

  // as an alternative, mark property list (or any other field) as observable.
  @observable 
  var properties = ...;
```

NOTE:
when a collection is marked `@observable`, UI elements bound to the collection are updated only when the collection object itself is changed (item added, removed, reordered), not when its contents are changed (e.g. an object in the list has some property modified). However, as your original properties list is an `ObservableList`, @observable annotation only serves here as a way to turn on the observable mechanism. Changes to the list are queued as a part of `ObservableList` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I think solution 2 (@observable) is better. As far as I know, watchers is the old way to track changes and will probably be removed.

Comment: Yes, it will be deprecated eventually.